# React server start failed (Works only if I restart the system)

Tags: reactjs

```
events.js:287
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/vishal/react/hacker-stories/public'
    at FSWatcher.start (internal/fs/watchers.js:169:26)
    at Object.watch (fs.js:1339:11)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/vishal/react/hacker-stories/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:38:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/vishal/react/hacker-stories/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:81:15)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/vishal/react/hacker-stories/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:233:14)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleDir (/home/vishal/react/hacker-stories/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:429:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/vishal/react/hacker-stories/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:477:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/vishal/react/hacker-stories/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:482:16)
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:168:5)
Emitted 'error' event on FSWatcher instance at:
    at FSWatcher._handleError (/home/vishal/react/hacker-stories/node_modules/chokidar/index.js:260:10)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/vishal/react/hacker-stories/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:40:5)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/vishal/react/hacker-stories/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:81:15)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:168:5) {
  errno: -28,
  syscall: 'watch',
  code: 'ENOSPC',
  path: '/home/vishal/react/hacker-stories/public',
  filename: '/home/vishal/react/hacker-stories/public'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

When I try to start my server with "yarn start" I'm getting this error. But when I restart my system it works. The problem is I can't restart my system every single time, so it'll be very helpful for me to get to know about some alter solution.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s hitting your system's file watchers limit

Try `echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p`

[Source](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/11406)